# Why are my Apple Developer emails blue?

Tags: mail.app

In Mail.app, the "Apple Developer" emails I get have a blue background, in the message list.  Why?  And how can I turn this off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mail automatically highlights emails from Apple. You can turn this off in the Rules tab of Mail Preferences.

Comment: Oh, I see it. I turned off that rule, but it's still blue.

Comment: Ah, I guess it applies the rule once and the color sticks, so I now have to use Format -> Color (command-shift-C) to reset their color to white.

Comment: Yeah that’s what happens. Rules are only applied when new email arrives.